# Vagrant SSH authentication failed

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

I've been working on setting up a vagrant box using Ubuntu for development purposes. I've been working on my base box. I setup a vagrant user, admin group, home directory, etc. I setup the

```
.ssh/authorized_keys
```

As mentioned [here](http://vagrantup.com/v1/docs/base_boxes.html), and installed chef + puppet. When I package the box and run vagrant up however, I get the title error message when the VM is booting up.

Hosts file on my mac:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

My Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.define :app do |app|
    app.vm.box = "ruby193-aaron"
    app.vm.box_url = "/Users/aaronmcleod/package.box"
    app.vm.network :hostonly, "192.168.100.35"
    app.vm.share_folder "v-root", "/vagrant", ".", :nfs => true
    app.vm.provision :shell, :path => "config/vagrant/app.sh"
    app.vm.host_name = "sojourner.vm"
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific on the 'title error message' that you're getting?

Comment: The full message is: "SSH authentication failed! This is typically caused by the public/private
keypair for the SSH user not being properly set on the guest VM. Please
verify that the guest VM is setup with the proper public key, and that
the private key path for Vagrant is setup properly as well." However, I have grabbed the example vagrant public key that is mentioned in the linked wiki.

Comment: Also, maybe check that the you've got the correct key (public key) listed in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the base vm. Also, make sure there is a file called insecure_private_key in ~/.vagrant.d on your local machine.

Answer (score 2):

Running `sudo vagrant up` fixed it for me.